# ShadowDOM: how do I repeat content?

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, shadow-dom, html5-template

So I know that, using Polymer, you can repeat content in the ShadowDOM tree by using the "repeat" attribute. But how do I do this in the native ShadowDOM spec? Is that possible?

In this example: http://css-tricks.com/modular-future-web-components/ the author uses nth-of-type function. But it works when you know how many times an element from the actual DOM is going to be repeated (4 in this case). What I would like to achieve is to be able to handle indefinite number of repetitions.

Comment: I don't think you can avoid using JS here and it's not very difficult with JS. So, if you use no frameworks, you shall try manipulating the DOM by hand. Otherwise there are AngularJS, Polymer, and other great frameworks. I recommend trying at least one of them, but maybe later.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty straightforward. Once you use a template, it's gone. So to repeat content, you'd just need to update the template with the content you want, and then make a clone of it, and use the clone that you just created.

**[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/TylerH/jkvw0x81/)**

```js
if ('content' in document.createElement('template')) {

var target = document.querySelector('.content-container'),
aside = target.content.querySelectorAll("aside");
aside[0].textContent = "Shadow DOM Content";
aside[1].textContent = "More Shadow DOM Content";
aside[2].textContent = "Even More Content!";

// Clone the new row and insert it into the table
var section = document.getElementsByClassName("first-section")
var clone = document.importNode(target.content, true);
section[0].appendChild(clone);

// Create a new row
aside[0].textContent = "test 1";
aside[1].textContent = "test 2";
aside[2].textContent = "test 3";

// Clone the new row and insert it into the table
var clone2 = document.importNode(target.content, true);
section[0].appendChild(clone2);

} else {
    // do something else
}
```

```css
body {
    background: lightgrey;
}

.first-section aside {
    background: grey;
    padding: 5px;
}

.first-section aside:nth-child(3n) {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="first-section">
        A repeated use of template:
    <div>
</div>

<template class="content-container">
    <aside></aside>
    <aside></aside>
    <aside></aside>
</template>
```

Using this method, you can re-use your template as many times as you like.